# Operators glitched? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, operators

For some reason in my program, the + sign adds two digits together, in my code:

```
numerator1 += wholenumber1 * denominator1;
```

If `wholenumber1` is `1` and `denominator1` is `4`, then the `numerator1` is `14`...  I found this out by:

```
console.log(numerator1);
```

This is using inputs with `type="number"`, and the other parts of the equation are working just fine...  But this part is essential in order for my program to run properly, and help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show this in the context you are using.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What you are describing happens if you don't pay attention to the types of variables and your first "number" is actually a string. In this case, if `numerator` holds a string value of 1 before the += operation, this will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the input `type` is `number`, the actual value is of type `string`. You can check this by `typeof` operator. So you have to use functions like `parseInt()` to convert the value to integer in order to perform actual arithmetic operation.

```js
console.log(typeof(document.getElementById('num1').value));
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" value="1"/>
```

**Code Example:**

```js
var numerator1 = 0;
var wholenumber1, denominator1;
wholenumber1 = document.getElementById('wholenumber1').value;
denominator1 = document.getElementById('denominator1').value;

numerator1 += parseInt(wholenumber1) * parseInt(denominator1);

console.log(numerator1);
```

```html
wholenumber1: <input type="number" value="1" id="wholenumber1" /> <br/>
denominator1: <input type="number" value="4" id="denominator1" />
```

Comment: I tried to use parseInt() but it still gave me the same answer...  It doesn't seem to be affecting any other part of my equation though...

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize I was adding a number to a string, ty!

Comment: @FilipPaul, because of `input type="number"` it is very usual to make mistake in this type of situation....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the input into integers for this to work.
You can use use `numerator1 += parseInt(wholenumber1) * parseInt(denominator1);`
Refer to [This](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) for more